# add same class to book and it's child pages

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I have book node with assigned article nodes as child pages. On certain books I want to be able to use different theming. Using context I can print additional css class on book page according to taxonomy. Is it somehow possible that the class can be passed to all child pages as well? I can not figure out some easy solution. The only way I can think of would be to mark child nodes too. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way I can think of if it's only about CSS, you can use `body` tag classes, it has different classes based on the nodes.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not of any use. There is no connection between parent book and it's childrens in body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two ways :

1. If you give each individual child nodes , individual class name.
2. You could use the nth child property to the nodes in the CSS part.

   **nth child property** could be added as

   ```
   p:nth-child(2){
          background:#ff0000;
   }
   ```